# Vuetify combobox calls computed setter twice on duplicate value

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm using Vue and Vuetify. I want to have a component that uses chips and will prevent duplicates. The default behavior is not allow duplicates, but there is no message to the user as to why they can't enter it. I created a computed property and on the setter, I check to see if there are duplicates in the list by doing a set and comparing the length. However, it appears the setter is called twice and never with all of the values. Here is a simple code example:

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container fluid>
      <v-row>
        <v-col cols="12">
          <v-combobox
            v-model="computedValue"
            label="I use chips"
            multiple
            chips
          ></v-combobox>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

and Javascript:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      value: []
    }
  },
  computed: {
    computedValue: {
      get: function() {
        return this.value
      },
      set: function(newValue) {
        console.log(newValue)
        this.value = newValue
      }
    }
  }
})
```

and here is a link to a CodePen  [example](https://codepen.io/dsaracini/pen/yLeGbWo)

steps to reduce:

- go to CodePen
- show console
- type 'a' (enter) 'b' (enter) 'c' (enter) 'a' (enter)

note the console.log messages

when typing the last 'a' you will see a two console outputs:

```
["b", "c"]
["b", "c", "a"]
```

My questions are:

1. How can I get access to the value entered before the setter is called so that I can tell the user.
2. Why is it called twice?

I really like the way that vuematerial.io chips work where it turns the duplicate red, but I don't see a good way of doing this here.

Comment: did you try using slots and some logic to define the color of duplicated  item?

Comment: Right now, I really don't see a way to even know if there was a duplicate entered. The setter gets called the first time and newValue is ["b", "c"]. Then immediately called again with "a" added to the end ["b", "c", "a"].  Basically, what I think is happening is that before calling the computed property, it removes "a" from the list, and sets the value, then does a array.push("a") and sets the value again. Thus, I can't really tell the difference if the user had accidentally deleted "a" and then re-added it. They look the same.

Comment: i noticed that, but i see that you just need a data value bound to your combobox model and you could use `value-comparator` prop in order to compare the entered value with the existing ones and inside it add some logic before returning the boolean value, for example you consider that values are not case sensitive

Comment: Interesting... I didn't know about value-comparator property. I was using a computed property so that I could have a setter as a way to have a hook. One of the uses of the control is I have a field where I allow the user to enter a list of file extensions to ignore when processing files. The backend job expects it to be include a "." and be lower-cased. So, I do that in the setter and update the data object. Let me see if I can make your suggestion work.

Comment: i tried to use `value-comparator` but this allows me to type just one item https://codepen.io/boussadjra/pen/OJMrOGj

Comment: Your compare function is called for each item in value...  But, the entered value has already been removed. if you return false, it will allow you to add multiple items. But, it doesn't help me. Because the newly entered value has already been removed from the array.

Comment: what about using `blur` event https://codepen.io/boussadjra/pen/yLeGvaO